# How to use google maps v2 on Android without load the map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

Is there a way to use google maps v2 on android without loading the map, I need to read the gps location when I click on a button, and calculate the distance between 2 points, I know how to do that but only if the map is loaded, I need a way to do that without the map, is this possible?

Comment: You can find the user's location using `LocationManager` or the fused location API from Play Services. You do not need a map for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can get location without map by using this code.

```
    startGPSBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(YourTab.this);
                if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
                    getLocation(startGPSBtn ,gps);
                    startGPSLatitude = String.valueOf(gps.getLatitude());
                    startGPSLongitude = String.valueOf(gps.getLongitude());
                } else {
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }
            }
    });
    endGPSBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(YourTab.this);
                if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
                    getLocation(endGPSBtn, gps);
                    endGPSLatitude = String.valueOf(gps.getLatitude());
                    endeGPSLongitude = String.valueOf(gps.getLongitude());
                } else {
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }

        }
    });
```

In additional you can check for internet is available or not , Device GPS is on or off.